# Delete query on a very large table running extremely slowly SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query:

```
delete from scans
    where scandatetime>(current_timestamp - interval '21 days') and
          scandatetime <> (select min(tt.scandatetime) from scans tt where tt.imb = scans.imb) and
          scandatetime <> (select max(tt.scandatetime) from scans tt where tt.imb = scans.imb)
;
```

That I use to delete records from the following table:

```
|imb        |scandatetime       |status   |scanfacilityzip|
+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------------+
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-02 04:50:22|Confirmed|12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-03 19:32:18|Processed|45867          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 10:24:16|Intake   |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 19:30:32|Received |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-02 02:15:52|Processed|84676          |
```

such that only 2 records remain per IMB, the one with the minimum scandatetime and the maximum scandatetime. I also limit this so it only performs this operation for records that are less than 3 weeks old. The resultant table looks like this:

```
|imb        |scandatetime       |status   |scanfacilityzip|
+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------------+
|isdijh23452|2020-01-01 13:45:12|Intake   |12345          |
|isdijh23452|2020-01-03 19:32:18|Processed|45867          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-01 10:24:16|Intake   |84676          |
|awgjnh09864|2020-01-02 02:15:52|Processed|84676          |
```

This table has a few indexes and has tens of millions of rows, so the query usually takes forever to run. How can I speed this up?

Explain output:

```
Delete on scans  (cost=0.57..115934571.45 rows=10015402 width=6)
  ->  Index Scan using scans_staging_scandatetime_idx on scans  (cost=0.57..115934571.45 rows=10015402 width=6)
        Index Cond: (scandatetime > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '21 days'::interval))
        Filter: ((scandatetime <> (SubPlan 2)) AND (scandatetime <> (SubPlan 4)))
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Result  (cost=3.91..3.92 rows=1 width=8)
                InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..3.91 rows=1 width=8)
                        ->  Index Only Scan using scans_staging_imb_scandatetime_idx on scans tt  (cost=0.70..16.79 rows=5 width=8)
                              Index Cond: ((imb = scans.imb) AND (scandatetime IS NOT NULL))
        SubPlan 4
          ->  Result  (cost=3.91..3.92 rows=1 width=8)
                InitPlan 3 (returns $3)
                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..3.91 rows=1 width=8)
                        ->  Index Only Scan Backward using scans_staging_imb_scandatetime_idx on scans tt_1  (cost=0.70..16.79 rows=5 width=8)
                              Index Cond: ((imb = scans.imb) AND (scandatetime IS NOT NULL))
```

Table DDL:

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE scans (
    imb text,
    scandatetime timestamp without time zone,
    status text,
    scanfacilityzip text
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE INDEX scans_staging_scandatetime_idx ON scans(scandatetime timestamp_ops);
CREATE INDEX scans_staging_imb_idx ON scans(imb text_ops);
CREATE INDEX scans_staging_status_idx ON scans(status text_ops);
CREATE INDEX scans_staging_scandatetime_status_idx ON scans(scandatetime timestamp_ops,status text_ops);
CREATE INDEX scans_staging_imb_scandatetime_idx ON scans(imb text_ops,scandatetime timestamp_ops);
```

Edit:
Here is the explain analyze output (note, I changed the interval to 1 day to make it run faster):

```
Delete on scans  (cost=0.58..3325615.74 rows=278811 width=6) (actual time=831562.877..831562.877 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using scans_staging_scandatetime_idx on scans  (cost=0.58..3325615.74 rows=278811 width=6) (actual time=831562.875..831562.875 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (scandatetime > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '1 day'::interval))
        Filter: ((scandatetime <> (SubPlan 2)) AND (scandatetime <> (SubPlan 4)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 277756
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Result  (cost=3.92..3.93 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.675..1.675 rows=1 loops=277756)
                InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..3.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.673..1.674 rows=1 loops=277756)
                        ->  Index Only Scan using scans_staging_imb_scandatetime_idx on scans tt  (cost=0.70..16.80 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=1.672..1.672 rows=1 loops=277756)
                              Index Cond: ((imb = scans.imb) AND (scandatetime IS NOT NULL))
                              Heap Fetches: 277761
        SubPlan 4
          ->  Result  (cost=3.92..3.93 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.086..0.086 rows=1 loops=164210)
                InitPlan 3 (returns $3)
                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..3.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.084..0.085 rows=1 loops=164210)
                        ->  Index Only Scan Backward using scans_staging_imb_scandatetime_idx on scans tt_1  (cost=0.70..16.80 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=0.083..0.083 rows=1 loops=164210)
                              Index Cond: ((imb = scans.imb) AND (scandatetime IS NOT NULL))
                              Heap Fetches: 164210
Planning Time: 11.360 ms
Execution Time: 831562.956 ms
```

EDIT: Result with explain analyze buffers:

```
Delete on scans  (cost=0.57..1274693.83 rows=103787 width=6) (actual time=19309.026..19309.027 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=743430 read=46033
  I/O Timings: read=15917.966
  ->  Index Scan using scans_staging_scandatetime_idx on scans  (cost=0.57..1274693.83 rows=103787 width=6) (actual time=19309.025..19309.025 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (scandatetime > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '1 day'::interval))
        Filter: ((scandatetime <> (SubPlan 2)) AND (scandatetime <> (SubPlan 4)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 74564
        Buffers: shared hit=743430 read=46033
        I/O Timings: read=15917.966
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Result  (cost=4.05..4.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.232..0.233 rows=1 loops=74564)
                Buffers: shared hit=458108 read=27849
                I/O Timings: read=15114.478
                InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..4.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.231..0.231 rows=1 loops=74564)
                        Buffers: shared hit=458108 read=27849
                        I/O Timings: read=15114.478
                        ->  Index Only Scan using scans_staging_imb_scandatetime_idx on scans tt  (cost=0.70..20.81 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.230..0.230 rows=1 loops=74564)
                              Index Cond: ((imb = scans.imb) AND (scandatetime IS NOT NULL))
                              Heap Fetches: 74583
                              Buffers: shared hit=458108 read=27849
                              I/O Timings: read=15114.478
        SubPlan 4
          ->  Result  (cost=4.05..4.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=1 loops=34497)
                Buffers: shared hit=228637 read=701
                I/O Timings: read=507.724
                InitPlan 3 (returns $3)
                  ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..4.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=34497)
                        Buffers: shared hit=228637 read=701
                        I/O Timings: read=507.724
                        ->  Index Only Scan Backward using scans_staging_imb_scandatetime_idx on scans tt_1  (cost=0.70..20.81 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=1 loops=34497)
                              Index Cond: ((imb = scans.imb) AND (scandatetime IS NOT NULL))
                              Heap Fetches: 34497
                              Buffers: shared hit=228637 read=701
                              I/O Timings: read=507.724
Planning Time: 5.350 ms
Execution Time: 19313.242 ms
```

Comment: What is *extremely slow*... *takes forever to run*? Please qualify with actual numeric comparison.

Comment: This query will take 30,000 seconds to run, if not more

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated with simple explain, will add analyze when it's done running

Comment: Per imb you want to keep 1. the newest row, 2. all rows older than 21 days, 3. if the oldest row is inside the last 21 days, then that one too. Yes?

Comment: Could you just change '21 days' to '1 day' for purposes of getting an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` more expeditiously?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner there would be no row older than 21 days because the provider we get this data from recycles all imb's every 21 days

Comment: How is this 'recycling' accomplished?  Maybe it is leaving your table/indexes in a very bloated state.  And it i mystery to me why your subplan 2 is so slow, while subplan 4 is not.  Maybe you include BUFFERS in the EXPLAIN it would provide a clue.

Comment: This data comes from an automated pipeline from one of our vendors. They are the ones that recycle IMBs every 21 days so while it's not necessarily likely to have an overlap it is certainly possible. I will run the explain with buffers and edit the post

Comment: @jjanes updated

Comment: If you replace `delete` with `select` is it fast? If so, the form of query is not the problem. If the query is running, what is the server really doing (CPU/IO)? Are there any triggers?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek changing delete to select makes little difference. There are no triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the pre-aggregation (and avoiding the CTE):

---

```
DELETE FROM scans del
WHERE del.scandatetime > (current_timestamp - interval '21 days')
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM scans x
        WHERE x.imb = del.imb
        AND x.scandatetime < del.scandatetime
        )
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM scans x
        WHERE x.imb = del.imb
        AND x.scandatetime > del.scandatetime
        )
        ;
```

---

The idea is: you only delete if there is (at least) one record before, and (at least) one after it. (with the same imd) This is not true for the first and last records, only the ones inbetween.

Comment: can you explain this a little more? it doesnt seem to me like this would keep the maximum and minimum timestamps. what if there were 4 scan events that were older than `del.scandatetime`, wouldn't it just delete them all as written?

Comment: I'm selecting this as an answer because it also works with Redshift. Redshift does not currently support the with clause in deletions

Comment: The CTE version can be very slow, too. In Postgres before Pg-12 (?) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider running aggregation *once* and incorporating it in an `EXISTS` clause.

```sql
with agg as (
   select imb
          , min(sub.scandatetime) as min_dt
          , max(sub.scandatetime) as max_dt
   from scans
   group by imb
)

delete from scans s
where s.scandatetime > (current_timestamp - interval '21 days')
  and exists
     (select 1
      from agg
      where s.imb = agg.imb
        and (s.scandatetime > agg.min_dt and
             s.scandatetime < agg.max_dt)
     );
```

Answer (score 2):

In the request comments you say that the table contains no rows older than 21 days. The condition `scandatetime > (current_timestamp - interval '21 days')` is hence superfluous. This also means that you delete almost all rows from the table. You only keep one or two rows per imb.

`DELETE` on so many rows (you mention tens of millions of rows) can be very slow. Not only must the table rows be deleted one by one, but also all the indexes updated.

This said, you may be better off copying those few desired rows into a temporary table, truncate the original table and copy the rows back. `TRUNCATE` doesn't look at single rows like `DELETE` does. It simply empties the whole table and its indexes in one go and immediately reclaims disk space.

The script would look something like this:

```
create table temp_desired_scans as
select *
from scans s
where (imb, scandatetime) in 
(
  select imb, min(scandatetime) from scans group by imb
  union all
  select imb, max(scandatetime) from scans group by imb
);

truncate table scans;

insert into scans
select * from temp_desired_scans;

drop table temp_desired_scans;
```

(Another common option for such mass deletes is to keep the temp table, drop the original table, rename the temp table to the original table's name and install all constraints and indexes on this new table.)

Comment: I misspoke in my comment, what I had meant to say is that basically after 21 days the data is considered final. We need to keep it because the IMBs represent actual scan events but after 21 days they reference new scan events that are wholly unrelated to the old ones. Essentially the data in the 21 day window is dynamic and anything older is static. We still need it.

Comment: Okay. Are you aware that your statement doesn't keep the first and last entry of the last 21 days? If the first entry for an imb is older, then you keep that (which you do anyway), but delete all rows in the last 21 days except for the newest one.

Comment: If you mainly work on the last 21 days in the table, you may want to consider partitioning the table by date.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that select is the problem, I would focus on just select. You can make a delete from it any time. You may try this form if it helps:

```
select * from
(select *,
    row_number() over (partition by imb order by scandatetime asc) ar,
    row_number() over (partition by imb order by scandatetime desc) dr
 from scans
)s 
where ar>1 and dr>1 and scandatetime>(current_timestamp - interval '21 days')
```